# Finding the value of $\tan \frac{u}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

Given that $\tan u = 0.4$ & $\pi<u<\frac{3\pi}{2}$. What's the value of $\tan \frac{u}{2}$ ??

I punched this info on calculator and my answer was $\frac{-5+\sqrt{29}}{2}$ but the answer given was $\frac{-5-\sqrt{29}}{2}$

Can anyone tell me how to solve this question completely without calculator ?

Comment: The answer below is of course correct. You have to be careful with the definition of $u$: if you know only that $\tan u=2/5$, then $u$ may be any value $\arctan(2/5)+k\pi$, thus $\tan(u/2)$ may be any value $\tan(\arctan(2/5)/2+k\pi/2)$. But here you are considering one specific value of $u$, which is **not** $\arctan(2/5)$ (since $\arctan x$ is always in $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$). Actually, $u=\arctan(2/5)+\pi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the formula for the tangent of a sum to obtain
$$
\tan(2x) = \frac{\tan(x)+\tan(x)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(x)} = \frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^{2}(x)}.
$$
Sustitute $u=2x$ and get
$$
\frac{2}{5} = 0.4 = \tan(u) = \tan(2x) = \frac{2\tan(x)}{1-\tan^{2}(x)} = \frac{2\tan\tfrac{u}{2}}{1-\tan^{2}\tfrac{u}{2}}.
$$
Rename $w=\tan\tfrac{u}{2}$, to get the equation
$$
\frac{2}{5} = \frac{2w}{1-w^{2}}.
$$
This becomes $1-w^{2} = 5w$, which leads $w^{2}+5w-1=0$ with roots
$$
w_{1} = \frac{-5+\sqrt{29}}{2}, \qquad w_{2} = \frac{-5-\sqrt{29}}{2}.
$$
Up to this point, the two posibilities are correct. However, $w_{1}$ is positive, while $w_{2}$ is negative. Since $\pi<u<\tfrac{3\pi}{2}$, we have $\tfrac{\pi}{2}<\tfrac{u}{2}<\tfrac{3\pi}{4}$. On that interval, the tangent function is negative. Thus, $w_{1}$ cannot be a solution, so it is $w_{2}$.